# How do I get overlay elements within the iframe

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I have created an overlay that sits on top of an iframe as can be seen at:
http://test.linkinformed.com/

I want the overlay elements to be within (or at least to appear within) the iframe.

The working solution would mean the red box stay on same section of page (ie on the page logo) when scrolling. Also, scrolling would not be blocked by the overlay layer as it is now.

Also the black menu bar at the top needs to stay static (ala stumbleupon, etc.)

EXAMPLE of what I want to do:
- User would use red box to select area on page (ie w3schools logo)
- They could then scroll to bottom of the page (red box would stay on logo and go out of view)
- They could then scroll back up to see the logo still in red box

Answer (score 1):

Try using `z-index` and `position` like below

```
On the red box add this to the css

  position:fixed;
  z-index:100;
```

Then make sure that the overlay has a `z-index` too.

```
z-index:99;
position:relative;//fixed, absolute etc
```

Comment: Changing z-index lets me put the box and overlay behind/in-front of the iframe. But not within the iframe. I've updated the question with an example ofwhat I am trying to do